# Swift 3 .dataTask error

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

After converting to Swift 3 I try to fix all the errors at the moment.
But this error makes me sick:

> Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type '(with: NSMutableURLRequest, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void)'

At this line of code (Its at the last line there) :

```
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let para = ["userId" : user_ID]
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    let imageA = images[pos]! as UIImage
    print(imageA)


    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageA, 1)

    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(para, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

The code continues here, but thats not important for the solution.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: The question here is how to fix it...  @matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler wants

```
var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
```

and

```
...(data: Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?)
```

but I recommend to omit the type annotations completely

```
...(data, response, error)
```

Comment: It _certainly_ wants Error, not NSError.

Comment: If i try it like that it the error just changed :  Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'  @vadian

Comment: Did you try also my updated `URLRequest` (`var` is important) ? You might also use `URL` rather than `NSURL`